# Hide MKUserLocation when MKMapView showsUserLocation == YES

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview, mkannotation

After setting `mapView.showsUserLocation` to true, is it possible to receive location updates without showing the MKUserLocation bubble? Returning nil in `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` simply shows the bubble, and returning any other kind of annotation shows an annotation, which I don't want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can hide the user location's view in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *ulv = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    ulv.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. I didn't realize you could manipulate MKAnnotationViews this way. Though I suppose it makes sense, as they are just UI objects. Thank you!

Comment: @Elgert, This method should be in the class that implements the MKMapView delegate (usually the one that contains the map view).  Make sure the map view's delegate property is set.

Comment: i did what you said and still the blue marker appears :(

Comment: @Elgert, Please ask a new question with details and the code you are using.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3:**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
   if let userLocation = mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation) {
        userLocation.isHidden = true
   }
}
```