# How to hide the blue dot and the circle on an MKMapView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there a easy way to hide it? I use the user location, but I don't want to show the blue dot. How can I hide it?

-- edit--

Am I using something wrong?

```
@interface ALMapaViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,
                                                    MKAnnotation>
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapaPrincipal;
    id<ALMapaViewControllerDelegate> delegateMap;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
}
```

my .m

```
@implementation ALMapaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mapaPrincipal setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapaPrincipal setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapaPrincipal setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [mapaPrincipal.userLocation addObserver:self 
                                forKeyPath:@"location" 
                                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
                                   context:nil];
    [mapaPrincipal setShowsUserLocation:YES]; 
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {      
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = mapaPrincipal.userLocation.coordinate;  
    MKCoordinateSpan span; 
    span.latitudeDelta  = 0.005f; 
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f; 
    region.span = span;
    [mapaPrincipal setRegion:region animated:YES];
    self.coordinate = region.center; 
    [mapaPrincipal addAnnotation:self];
    [mapaPrincipal setShowsUserLocation:NO];
}
@end
```

I already used the `showUserLocation` and it still show the blue dots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to receive user location updates but not show the blue dot.

One option is to use `CLLocationManager` to get updates instead of the map view's `showsUserLocation`.  Call `startUpdatingLocation` on the location manager and implement its `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` delegate method.

If you don't want to use `CLLocationManager`, another option is to hide the user location view that is created by the map view by setting it's `hidden` property to `YES` in the map view's `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method.  The map view will continue to receive user location updates (because you are **not** setting `showsUserLocation` to `NO`) but the blue dot won't show because you're hiding its view.

An example of the second option is shown in this answer:
[Hide MKUserLocation when MKMapView showsUserLocation == YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711874/hide-mkuserlocation-when-mkmapview-showsuserlocation-yes)

An unrelated point is that you don't need to use key-value-observing to monitor changes to the map view's `userLocation` property.  Use the `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` delegate method instead.

Answer (score 6):

Very simple buddy

```
[mapView setShowUserLocation:NO];
```

Comment: I used it. But it don't work. What this do is: update or not my current local. This still show the blue dot.

Comment: @C4-Travis sorry for delay, but i put it. Look, I already use this property and don't work for this.

Comment: @Rodrigo you have set this property to yes that is why it's displaying the blue dot..
    [mapaPrincipal setShowsUserLocation:YES]; 

change this to this
    [mapaPrincipal setShowsUserLocation:NO];

Comment: this is the problem. Ok, if I set to no, it don't show the blue dot, but don't show my place too. I want know my location. Like you see, if I set YES, it show my place, but if I set NO after this, the blue dot don't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the user location's view in the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method:

```
(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
  { 
    MKAnnotationView *ulv = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
    ulv.hidden = YES;
  }
```

check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713085/1344237

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

[mapViewSelf setShowsUserLocation:NO];

Answer (score 0):

this works fine.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews (NSArray<MKAnnotationView *> *)views {
  MKAnnotationView *ulv = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
  if (ulv) {
    CALayer *layer = [ulv valueForKeyPath:@"_accuracyLayer"];
    if (layer) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer is correct, hiding it is very effective.  Here's the delegate implemented code the accepted answer was referring to:

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        if let userView = views.first(where: { $0.annotation is MKUserLocation }) {
             userView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```