# How to remove blue dot from MkMapView when user click on MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem?

Tags: mkmapview

**I am using MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem in MkMap. I have to remove blue dot from makmap.**

Comment: Are you saying you want to hide the blue dot but _still_ track the user's location using didUpdateUserLocation?  If so, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711874/hide-mkuserlocation-when-mkmapview-showsuserlocation-yes.